# scrapy pipeline to JSON with Chinese characters

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I'm trying to scrapy some web contents with Chinese character. the content scraped like below

```
2018-11-20 12:42:18 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200  https://cn.bing.com/dict/search?q=tool&FORM=BDVSP6&mkt=zh-cn>
{'defBing': '工具；方法；受人利用的人',
 'defWeb': '工具；方法；受人利用的人',
 'pClass': 'n.',
 'prUK': 'UK\xa0[tuːl]',
 'prUS': 'US\xa0[tul]',
 'word': 'tool'}
```

But after the pipeline process, the content has been like this:

```
{
    "word": "tool",
    "prUS": "US\u00a0[tul]",
    "prUK": "UK\u00a0[tu\u02d0l]",
    "pClass": "n.",
    "defBing": "\u5de5\u5177\uff1b\u65b9\u6cd5\uff1b\u53d7\u4eba\u5229\u7528\u7684\u4eba",
    "defWeb": "\u5de5\u5177\uff1b\u65b9\u6cd5\uff1b\u53d7\u4eba\u5229\u7528\u7684\u4eba"
}
```

The pipeline looks like:

```
class JsonWriterPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('log/DICT.%s.json' % time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S', time.localtime()), 'tw')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            line = json.dumps(dict(item), indent=4) + "\n"
            self.file.write(line)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return item
```

my question is: **how can I keep the Chinese character printed as-is in the *.json file?** I really don't want those encoded Unicode characters :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the json lib escape those symbols, try to add `ensure_ascii=False` to `json.dumps()` as follow:

```
class JsonWriterPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.file = open('log/DICT.%s.json' % time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S', time.localtime()), 'tw')

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:
            line = json.dumps(dict(item), indent=4, ensure_ascii=False) + "\n"
            self.file.write(line)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return item
```